# Basic question regarding third octave filters

Tags: filters, signal-analysis, octave

I would like to use third octave filters on a time signal. 
Do I have to apply all third octave filters to a single frequency or do I only need to apply the one that has its center frequency the closest to the frequency that I am looking at?

I would like to use a simple example to make my quesion clear:
Let's say I have a basic sin signal: `signal = sin(2*pi*f*t)` with f = 57Hz.
57Hz is almost right between the center frequencies of 50Hz and 63Hz, but the closest would be 63Hz. Do I apply all filters or only the one with a center frequency of 63Hz?

I am pretty sure that the answer is that I will always have to apply all filters in theory. Of course filters with much higher center frequencies will result in insignificant amplitudes...

Comment: To what *end* do you want to use these filters? I think you'll find the answer when you simply explicitly write down *why* you want to use them.

Comment: I want to use the filters to get a frequency spectrum in which all amplitudes are assigned to third octave center frequencies. This would allow me to summate these amplitudes with other amplitudes that are also assigned to the third octave center frequencies.

Comment: sooooo do you know beforehand which filters will not contain energy or do you want to look at the output to figure what the spectrum looks like?

Comment: My current plan is to perform a fft on the time signal to know up to which frequency I will have to use filters. So yes, I know the spectrum before filtering, but I don't necessarily know if a certain filter contains a significant amount of energy.

Comment: well, if you don't know which filter is going to contain energy or not, you'll have to run it on the signal anyway to figure that out, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you're right and my problem is solved as well. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: This is no different than an FFT: each filter is a bin, skip one and your results are bogus.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Yes, you're right. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Someone released my natural inheritences and regulatory systems calculated as it formed my employment, rewards  and inheritences payable to me obly all as one from more than just my g.c., Tricon, Albertsons, Tetra,  and more...as someone or a group if someones have changed my statuses to a protective state and have done so as if court ordered. I gave nevet in my life been so isolated during major life upsets such as missing children and death with zero compliance of the government and of others involved. My personally named for claim and my personal poatal mail and hijacked emails go uncorresponded and still remail displaced like my paymemt and documentations I have  applied for in the last entire seven years and my lifes worth is wromgly dispensed. From my insurance policies to my ach as named, global this state is acting as if I am dead. Even as the shut down goes, these are being processed illegally like my procured custody reformed payments from my base assigned living EXPOSURE money. 
A step father and father with uncle's and aunts steal. Like they always have.
I am Lindsey ann maxfields
717 briarwood lane Hurst rd.

Comment: Well, that escalated quickly...